# SIGSEGV when reading config with libconfig

Tags: c, libconfig

I can't retrieve the user value from my config file using C and libconfig.

**configreader.h**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <libconfig.h>
#ifndef CONFIGREADER_H_INCLUDED
#define CONFIGREADER_H_INCLUDED

char *userreader(){
    static const char *inputfile = "/opt/plaininc/config/handler.conf";
    config_t configreader;
    const char *userconfig;
    if(! config_read_file(&configreader, inputfile)){
        config_destroy(&configreader);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    }
    if (config_lookup_string(&configreader, "handler.user", &userconfig)){
        config_destroy(&configreader);
        return userconfig;

    } else {
        config_destroy(&configreader);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    }
}

#endif
```

**CONFIG.c**

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "configreader.h"

int main(){
    const char *user = userreader();
    printf("%s", user);
}
```

GDB:

> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. 0xb7e63496 in
>   free () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6

Comment: What does `config_destroy` do?

Comment: Why is there a function in the header file?
And please include all the code needed to reproduce the error

Comment: @tkausl config_destroy() destroys the configuration config, deallocating all memory associated with the configuration, but does not attempt to deallocate the config_t structure itself.

Comment: Apparantly config_destroy() assumes the configreader is located on the heap. So you should do:
config_t *configreader = malloc(sizeof(config_t));
Currently your configreader is on the stack so it makes no sense to deallocate it, since that would happen upon returning from the function

Comment: [link] (https://pastebin.com/HXh9d6iR) @Unh0lys0da I tried that.

Comment: I don't know what you tried, but it tries to free something that is not in the heap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize `configreader` using [`config_init()`](http://www.hyperrealm.com/libconfig/libconfig_manual.html#The-C-API). Do:

```
config_t configreader;
const char *userconfig;
config_init(&configreader);
....
```

Comment: Thank you!! I missed config_init(). I'm "blind" sometimes :v